# Error:(8, 35) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout'

Tags: android

I am completely new to Android app devlopement and just started watching one video training and have installed andriod studio. I have created a program to print "hello world"" but it's giving few errors which I have no idea as that training is very basic and has no info on errors.

My code is:(Basically this is auto generated code when I started new project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And it is giving following errors:

```
Error:(8, 35) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'x' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'x' is not a valid element in a schema document.
Error:(1, 56) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding first.

Comment: Thanks @OjasviBhargava I tried that but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to the build.gradle (app)

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

or download constraint layout from [here](https://prnt.sc/ho1w9l)

Comment: Thanks @OjasviBhargava but It's already there in build.gradle as follows:                                                                         
      dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}